SUMIF formula not working with linked and formatted cells
Im trying to make a simple calorie counting sheet as a protoype to an app, users answer a form whose data is loaded into a sheet and then a page which calculates a daily count but the criterion is dd/mm/yyy and the range to check for matches is autoformatted from google forms as dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss and i can't figure out the formula to make it work.
I tried formatting using this: Google Sheets SUMIF Using Partial Date/Time Stamp as Wild Card Criteria
and a host of other solutions but can't figure out what is going on.
Im trying to make it as stupidly simple as possible and reduce manual labour, which is why I want to make formulas to add all entries from a single date.
I wanted to simply use sumif like if column a has a1's mm/dd/yyy then add em up: =SUMIF('Form Responses 1'!A:A,A2,'Form Responses 1'!C:C)
enter image description here
I've been going at this for a while trying to find what formula to use and I just don't get it.
Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A3oHyjzqoCctaaPuNGpAPia0vqU6A6Ud9C1Znyb3StE/edit?usp=sharing
